# How to setup dev environment like egghead.io videos

Tags: angularjs, development-environment

I want to setup a environment on my machine to learn AngularJS. I saw in the videos of [egghead.io](https://egghead.io/) where he keeps typing AngularJS code and when it  refreshes through a server and displays the changes in realtime in the browser. How to do that? I see WebStrom logo in the videos but that's it.

Comment: Do accept the answer when you see it working.. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, cofounder of egghead here. It really depends on the lesson you are watching as all of the instructors use different tools. None of them use Yeoman though, as the accepted answer suggests. Browsersync is awesome. It's author Shane Osbourne is an egghead instructor https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-gulp-and-browserify-adding-live-reload-with-browsersync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a server to setup your files. The videos you saw might have used browser-reload plugin which watches the files for changes and refreshes the page as soon as there's a change in any of the files.
You can use [*yeoman*](http://yeoman.io/) (and one of the generators) for project setup (for scaffolding basically). You will need to install [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/) first which will install NPM (node package manager) with it. Then you can install *YEOMAN* and use the generator respectively. My recommendation would be [generator-gulp-angular](https://github.com/swiip/generator-gulp-angular#readme). 
See the readme for the instructions, but basically you'll have to run these commands in command prompt after you've installed NodeJS properly.

```
npm install -g yo gulp bower
```

the above command installs yeoman,gulp and bower respectively

```
npm install -g generator-gulp-angular
```

the above command installs the gulp-angular yeoman generator

Then you can create a directory, say 'testDir' and navigate into it. I.e.

```
cd testDir
```

Then run

```
yo gulp-angular
```

You'll be asked to select desired technologies. Once you're done, you can run the following command to see it working (with live reload)

```
gulp serve
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what video you're talking about but it sounds like he/she has a gulp or grunt task that is watching for changes and then livereloading your browser. It could be either

- gulp-livereload (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-livereload)

or

- browsersync (https://www.browsersync.io/)